# Systemctl commands timeout when ran as root

Tags: linux, systemd

Since today when I try to execute `systemctl` using the root account they fail with a `Connection timed out` error:

```
>sudo systemctl
>Failed to list units: Connection timed out
```

The same thing occurs with `systemctl start` or `systemctl stop` *when ran as root*.

If I try to run the same commands using an user account, I don't get the `Connection timed out` error (start and stop give the expected error due to lack of permissions in user account).

If I reboot the server, all services that I'm aware of start correctly but I still get the same timeout errors.

PD: Using openSuse 13.2 (Linux version 3.16.7-21-default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem.

I figured that process 1 (systemd) was started with *--switched-root* and *--deserialize*. 
And as I found in [that link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98128/what-are-the-systemd-command-line-options-switched-root-and-deserialize) it seems that there are some internal parameters which try to reload some previously saved state.

I've done a kill -9 on process 1 an now the systemd appears without the switched-root and systemctl is working again with or without rebooting.

Comment: I'm also using openSuse 13.2 and have the same problem, but kill -9 doesn't work in my case, as systemd seems to ignore it. Using systemctl daemon-reexec instead restarts it (and is the only systemctl operation that doesn't time out), but with the same parameters, so I keep getting the timeouts afterwards. Any idea how to force it? I can't tell from the link you posted to the other thread if this is strictly required when using initramfs.

Comment: Neither `kill -9 1` or `systemctl daemon-reexec` worked for me so I resorted to the big red switch that is `reboot`.  But that did not work!  _(Failed to start reboot.target: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out.  See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.  Failed to open /dev/initctl: No such device or address.  Failed to talk to init daemon.)_  After a bit of googling I found `systemctl --force --force reboot` (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355822&p=13621891#post13621891) did a reboot and appears to be back to normal

Comment: It worked for me on elementaryOS loki, got stuck after configuring TightVNC server, but now it works like a charm.

Comment: None of all the above worked for me.

Comment: I am getting this issue and it becomes really annoying. Neither kill -9 1 or systemctl daemon-reexec worked. The only solution if found working is the reboot double forced but after 2 days, the problem is back !

Answer (score 5):

Two alternative solutions to the problem:

1- rebooting with

```
systemctl --force --force reboot
```

or

2- without reboot, just moving session files

```
mv /run/systemd/system/session-*.scope /tmp/
```

Comment: Warning!  `systemctl --force --force reboot` reboots the server, not just the service!

Comment: yes, that is the meaning of `reboot`. you `reboot` the server and `restart` the service.

Comment: Option #1 solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason you may see this is when `systemd` is run in virtualized environments. If the different instances of `systemd` get the same machine id from the filesystem (`/etc/machine-id`) or [from other fallback methods](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/machine-id-setup.c#L28), the system will become unstable and you will see this error when using `systemctl` or other systemd utils.

I can verify this happens with docker containers which use `systemd` processes as the entry point. Adding this to help others troubleshoot this obscure error.